# how to implement attribute pop in python

Tags: python

In Python the dict object has a "pop" method which returns and removes a key from a dict, with an optional default if the key doesn't exist.

What is the best way to do this for general object attributes?

I'm thinking:

```
my_obj.__dict__.pop('key_name', default)
```

Should be a good option but I'm worried that directly muting the object's **dict** might have unintended side effects that I'm not aware of. Is there a better option?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's usually not a good idea to treat object attributes this way in Python.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? i mean, you'd use `my_obj.pop('key_name', default)`, and then you'd implement to do something that makes sense for your object, which will be different if it represents an ion storm or an ice cream truck...

Comment: Just because the attributes of an object are implemented with a dictionary doesn't mean it makes sense for an object itself to support a `pop` operation. Part of object-oriented design is that each instance of a class shares certain properties defined by the class. Removing such a property from one object but not another breaks that design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(for objects with a `__dict__`) "popping" an attribute is the same thing as popping it from the `__dict__`, and therefor your suggested implementation is correct.

EDIT: @Erik correctly pointed out that using `__dict__.pop` can raise a `KeyError`, where the apporpriate exception is an `AttributeError`. So a better implementation would add try/catch/reraise-as-AttributeError.

I would just point out that what you're trying to do is "popping" an *attribute* of an object, not a *key*.

Comment: Ok this might be a stupid question but...doesn't every new-style object have a ```__dict__``` attribute? It's built into the language itself.

Comment: no. e.g. if they use [slots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/python-slots) or if they are types implemented in an extension (e.g. numpy arrays)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** A possibly faster and thread safe alternative with proper mapping of `KeyError` to `AttributeError`:

```
_NO_DEFAULT = object()  # so that None could be used as a default value also

def popattr(obj, name, default=_NO_DEFAULT):
    try:
        return obj.__dict__.pop(name)
    except KeyError:
        if default is not _NO_DEFAULT:
            return default
        raise AttributeError("no attribute '%s'" % name)
        # or getattr(obj, name) to generate a real AttributeError
```

**(previous answer)**

Something like this should work:

```
def popattr(obj, name):
    ret = getattr(obj, name)
    delattr(obj, name)
    return ret
```

Although `obj.__dict__.pop(name)` also works but you'll get a `KeyError` in case of non-existent attributes as opposed to `AttributeError`, and I'd say the latter is semantically correct for object attribute access; `KeyError` is used for dictionaries, but you're not *really* accessing a dictionary; the fact that you're using `__dict__` is just an implementation detail of attribute popping and should be hidden, which is what `popattr` does.

Comment: @Ben: sorry, my bad; fixed (and simplified)

Comment: using `obj.__dict__.pop`, like OP suggested, is better for being faster, and atomic (thus thread-safe). Your point about `KeyError` vs `AttributeError` is a good point though.

Comment: @shx2: I've added a solution that covers both aspects.

Comment: That'd do. I'd add `*args` to support a default value, because it seems like that's the functionality th OP is after.

Comment: `*args` would be more compact but the argument signature of the function would suffer then (e.g. if you're used to doing `<callable>?` in IPython.